# Solving $\cos3\alpha = 2\sin3\alpha $

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the following equation:
> $$\cos3\alpha = 2\sin3\alpha $$

I am stuck. I am confused by the $2 \cdot \sin3 \alpha$
Division by that same seems very incorrect.

Any smart tips, or approach is much appreciated.

**Adding:** Solving with *Documentation* for step-by-step process, mathematically.

**Edit** How to go from to this?

$$\cos3\alpha = 2\sin3\alpha \implies \tan(3\alpha) = \frac{\sin3\alpha}{\cos3\alpha}$$

If, it was like this, I would know.
$$\cos3\alpha = \sin3\alpha \implies \tan(3\alpha) = \frac{\sin3\alpha}{\cos3\alpha}$$

But, it isn't. I am trying to get an answer to, how to eliminate the 2 in front of the $\sin3\alpha$ ? Since it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Notice that $\tan(3\alpha)=\frac12$

Comment: Dividing is only invalid when $2 \sin 3 \alpha = 0$.

Comment: @robjohn, thx. I know this. But, *How do you document, how you broke away?* meaning, how you get from this equation to writing: $tan(3\alpha) = \frac{sin3\alpha}{cos3\alpha}$ ?

Comment: Dividing the equation by $\cos(3\alpha)$ is valid as long as $\cos(3\alpha)\ne0$. If $\cos(3\alpha)=0$, then $\sin(3\alpha)$ is either $+1$ or $-1$, and the equation is not satisfied; so we know that $\cos(3\alpha)\ne0$.

Comment: Well you just separate two cases: one where $\cos 3 \alpha$ is equal to zero, which you can solve by inspection, and the case when it is not zero, in which case division of both sides by it is valid.

Comment: @JohnSmith You document by breaking into two parts (1) You say : IF $2 \sin 3 \alpha = 0$, then (some working involving known values of the sine) and these are the solutions for $\alpha$. (2) If NOT, then $2 \sin 3 \alpha \neq 0$, hence I can divide by it , and (some working involving known values of the tangent) and these are the solutions for $\alpha$. So you've split into cases : one where you can use the values of $\sin$ and one where you can divide by it and use the values of $\tan$. (Note : if you are looking to verify a solution, we'll add the solution-verification tag).

Comment: OH, I see the issue now @JohnSmith that $2$ doesn't go anywhere. You just get $\tan(3 \alpha) =2$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, but, isn't there a mathematically required step, to document how you do this?

Comment: @JohnSmith That mathematical step is as follows : you may divide an equation by the same quantity on both sides, provided that the quantity is not zero. Now, I reminded you to break into two cases earlier : when $\sin 3 \alpha = 0$ and when $\sin 3 \alpha \neq 0$. In the latter case, you may use the division law to divide both sides by $\sin 3 \alpha$. This gives $\frac{\cos 3 \alpha}{\sin 3 \alpha} = \frac{2 \sin 3 \alpha}{\sin 3 \alpha}$. Now, on the left hand side, we know the definition of $\tan$, so that is $\tan 3 \alpha$. On the right hand side, we get cancellations which give $2$.

Comment: Thus, $\tan 3 \alpha = 2$. Now we have to solve this. (Note : for the case when $\sin 3 \alpha = 0$, you can find all values of $\alpha$ which satisfy this equation and then check if each of those satisfies $\cos 3 \alpha = 0$ or not. There will not be any solutions.)

Comment: There's nothing mathematically that shows how you are cancelling on the right-hand side?

Comment: @JohnSmith That's also a rule, right? If $b \neq 0$ and $a$ is any number, then $\frac{ab}{b} = a$. These are rules that usually are performed without having to explicitly specify them. Usually because if someone can understand a trigonometric equation they will have gone through the basic of algebraic operations before that, and so won't feel the need to specify steps. If your teacher is making you do this then I'm sorry about these circumstances : I find these little things unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnSmith, if you _really_ want to write a reason for why $\frac{ab}{b} = a$ for $b \neq 0$ recall that the real numbers form a field, and one of the [field axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) is that for any $ b \neq 0$ there exists a number $b^{-1}$ such that $b^{-1} b = b b^{-1} = 1$. With this in mind, and noting that $\frac{x}{y}$ is just notation for $x y^{-1}$ we see that
$$
\frac{ab}{b} = (ab)(b^{-1}) = a(b b^{-1}) = a (1) = a
$$
where we also used the associativity axiom for multiplication and the multiplicative identity axiom.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Just to be nit-picky: $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$; $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\cot(x)$.

Comment: @robjohn good point! I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $\theta=3\alpha$, then $\cos \theta=2 \sin \theta$. Square both sides and use $\cos^2 \theta=1-\sin^2 \theta$ to get a quadratic equation.  Now, just solve the quadratic to find $\sin\theta$. Then, find $\theta$ and $\alpha$.